# JS как получить данные при вызове генератора с асинхронной функцией

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Изучаю JS генераторы.

https://codepen.io/ulibka68/pen/wvapYpz

Внутри генератора стоит вызов асинхронной функции fetch.
Пока результат выполнения fetch удается получить только в этой строке:

if (nextResult.done) {
      console.log('nextResult.value ',nextResult.value);

Подскажите пожалуйста правильный паттерн использования генератора с асинхронной функцией.
В том смысле чтобы можно было вызвать callGenerator и получить данные от fetch

P.S. Я прекрасно знаю как пользоваться fetch - здесь она используется просто как пример асинхронной функции, возвращающей promise.

```js
function* generatorCreator () {
  const response = yield fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1');
  const data = yield response.json();
//   console.log(data);
  return(data);
}

const callGenerator = () => {
  const iterator = generatorCreator();
  
  let cnt=1;

  function next(value) {
    console.log('cnt ',cnt++);
    const nextResult = iterator.next(value);
    
    if (nextResult.done) {
      console.log('nextResult.value ',nextResult.value);
       return nextResult.value;
    } else {
       nextResult.value.then(next);
    }

    return 'Я работаю';
  };
  
   let result = next();
   console.log('result =>',result);
}

callGenerator();
```

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/async-iterators-generators

Comment: Спасибо! Этот код я взял из статьи.

Как Вы думаете - код изначально написан неверно?
Меня тоже смущает что нигде нет ни async ни await, но тем не менее он как то работает.

Comment: у меня есть смутное, эфимерное ощущение, что на MDN в описании async/await, в конце стать был пример полифилла как раз на генераторах. но я не могу найти достоверную инфу

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11725

Comment: Ах, да!  https://learn.javascript.ru/async-await